# For In Loop animations being skipped when the array contains duplicates

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, animation, uibutton

I have a function that iterates over an array of UIButtons and animates each button one by one in the array. Currently this all works perfectly until a button is appended to the array more than once then it skips the animation for both instances. Is there a way to stop this behaviour?

```
func animateButtons() {
        disableButtons()

        for (index, button) in buttonSequence.enumerated() {
            group.enter()
            UIButton.animate(
                withDuration: 1,
                delay: TimeInterval(index),
                animations: {
                    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 63/255, green: 255/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)
                },
                completion: { finished in
                    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 168/255, green: 61/255, blue: 164/255, alpha: 0.85)
                    self.group.leave()
                }
            )
        }

        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            self.enableButtons()
        }
    }
```

Comment: why not add delay to animation while iterating, if you want buttons to animate one after another?

Comment: This is a misuse of dispatch group. You should recurse by way of the completion handler, or use key frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your for loop with artificial `delay` parameters is completely wrong. The way to chain animations is with a keyframe animation or using recursion. In this case I would suggest recursion. Here's a simple working example; this is the *complete* code for an app with two buttons plus some way to trigger the `start` function, so try it out for yourself:

```
func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    func start() {
        // starting, disable buttons
        let buttonSequence : [UIButton] = [ button1, button2, button1, button1, button2 ]
        self.animate(buttonSequence)
    }
    func animate(_ seq:[UIButton]) {
        if let b = seq.first {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
                b.backgroundColor = .red
            }) { _ in
                b.backgroundColor = nil
                delay(0.1) {
                    self.animate(Array(seq.dropFirst()))
                }
            }
        } else {
            // done, enable buttons
        }
    }
}
```